# C++ stoi sometimes sends exception with spaces

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++11, integer

so this might be a very obvious question for some, but i have no idea of where to start on this error.

I have some code that reads some strings from a .txt file, all strings have a ":" and then after a number. Example:

Objects per color: 1

Amount of Robots: 10

Predefined positions: 1

When I edit the values by hand, the stoi works fine, but when a c# code writes the values to the same file (note that i have checked by hand, and there are identical, no extra spaces, no extra characters, nothing visually different) the stoi complains. My code is the next:

c++:

```
cout << "Number..." << endl;
cout << dataLine.substr(dataLine.find_first_of(":")+1) << endl;
try{
    cfgVals.push_back(stoi(dataLine.substr(dataLine.find_first_of(":")+1)));    
}catch(exception& ex){
    cout << ex.what() << endl;
}
```

In both cases, the cout of dataline sends a space and then the number " 1" or " 10". When the file is edited by me, stoi doesn't throw an exception, but edited by the other program, it does (and nevertheless it seems to do the conversion right anyway).

The command that I use to write the file in c# is very simple:

```
File.WriteAllLines(@nameFile, param);
```

Where param is a list of strings.

Hope I am clear enough, any idea? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you ever consider about character encode? maybe your "C#" write file as 'UTF-8', and as I know 'stoi' is dealing with 'ASCII'

Comment: What is the exception - i.e. what does ex.what() return?

Comment: @Freeman Zhang, you might be up to something... Ill have a look at that.

Comment: @Anon Mail, basically an invalid argument exception.

Comment: Hmm, there may be a lot of reasons for a non printable character to cause a read error. Please show an hexadecimal dump of the file you write *by hand* and of the file generated by the C# code - [vim](http://www.vim.org) or [notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/) are know to be able to generate such dumps.

Comment: My guess would be different line breaks, `\r\n` for C# and `\n` for you editor. When reading, you get empty lines between your correct lines, which explains why you see an exception and still get the correct values in `cfgVals`.

Comment: @KarstenKoop Not in this case, I also though about this, but I checked and I took away the \r beacuse of this same reason. When the file is created, no empty lines appear and I'm using only \n.

Comment: You are using `WriteAllLines`, which should use `\r\n`. How did you take away the `\r`?

Comment: @SergeBallesta I assume (correct me if I'm wrong) you cant to see the value of the space in hex. I checked in both cases and is 20. What I found was the jump line, in the one made by C# it is 0A 0D 0A, the one made by hand is 0D 0A only.

Comment: @KarstenKoop you are right on that, my bad!

Comment: @KarstenKoop my mistake was adding a \n and using writealllines, I was adding an extra jump (as you mentioned). It now works as it has to. Would you please post this as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you see that behaviour of your C++ program depends on a program that creates input file, you should check what encoding is using by that C#-program and what encoding do you use to save file from the text processor. You can also send here code of C#-program that creates this file.

Comment: Long time ago I got this answer and I managed to fix it. In fact it was a wrong encoding!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, stoi will throw an exception if it does not get an input it can convert into an integer -- a space character is not a number nor can it be part of a number. You can trim the input by removing the space in front before feeding it to stoi and that should solve your problem.

```
string trim(string num)
{
  string res = "";
  if (num[0] == ' ') {
    res = num.substr(1);
  }
  return res;
}
```

this should do the job, assuming that in front is the only place you have the space characters